# Form fields stability when using jquery to create the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I am using json to fill the options of select tag, when I choose the country, system synchronously fill the combobox of cities

```
<label class="AddressLable">الدوله</label>
                <select name="country"  id="countryCB">
                <option >اختر</option>
                <?php $cntr=0;      
                while($cntr < count($countries))
                {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $countries[$cntr]['countryNo']?>" <?php echo $_POST['country']==$countries[$cntr]['countryNo']?'selected':''?>> <?php echo $countries[$cntr]['countryName'];?></option>

                <?php 
                $cntr++;
                }
                ?>
                </select>

                <label class="AddressLable">المدينة</label>
                <select name="city" id="cityCB">

                </select>
```

//here is the jquery script

```
$("#countryCB").change(function(){
    var countryNo=$(this).val();
    var param={"action":"getCities",
                "countryNo":countryNo
    };
    $.getJSON("controllers/Customer.controller.php",param,function(result){
        input=$("#cityCB");
        $('>option',input).remove();
        $("#cityCB").append('<option> اختر</option>');
        $.each(result,function(i,val){

        var option = $('<option />');
        option.attr("value",val.cityNo);
        option.text(val.cityName);
        $("#cityCB").append(option);
        })
    });
```

How can I make something like this:

```
<?php echo $_POST['country']==$countries[$cntr]['countryNo']?'selected':''?>
```

in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("cityCB option[value='your_value']").attr("selected", true);
```

Run it after you append all of the options.

Comment: The value is defined dynamically !

Comment: So don't copypaste the example, modify it to suit your needs. Determine what value you want selected and use the above code snippet. If you don't want to or cba to do so, then I'm afraid someone else will have to do the work for you.

Comment: I make like this $("cityCB value='<?php echo $_POST['city'] ?>'").attr("selected", true); onpage load, but it doesn't work! even I put the javascript code in the php file!

Comment: That doesn't even resemble the snippet I posted.